# Trying to get Scrollspy working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've read through & followed some examples from this forum, but I cannot get scrollspy to work  at all.

I fear I may be missing something stupid, heres my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pickledegg/2DV5L/9/

and heres one that works, http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/SZYKM/ hope someone can tell me whats up with mine!

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach the ScrollSpy plugin to the element which *triggers* the **scroll** events, which in your case is not the body.

```
<div class="stuff" data-spy="scroll">
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/2DV5L/10/)